# Three.js make Object3D Child face Camera

Tags: three.js

I have an Object3D which gets rotated and has a plane as child, how can I make the plane to always face the camera?

```
var obj = new THREE.Object3D()
var plane = new THREE.Mesh()

obj.add(plane)
plane.lookAt(camera.position)
```

Comment: You need to control your character? Like this: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

Comment: no, my object has a plane which is a texture that i created with canvas2d and it should always face the camera, camera can rotate arround obj, obj itself can also move and rotate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update for three.js r107:

`plane.lookAt(camera.getWorldPosition(v));`

is now doing what OP requested, whereas the old Solution is behaving differently. Updated the example: http://jsfiddle.net/7xj98f61/

---

Use [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1752#issuecomment-5454286) `lookAtWorld` addition from zz85

```
THREE.Object3D.prototype.lookAtWorld = function( vector ) {

  this.parent.worldToLocal( vector );
  this.lookAt( vector );

}
```

Or just hack it in like:

```
function animate() {
    /* ... */
    var vector = plane.parent.worldToLocal( camera.getWorldPosition() );
    plane.lookAt( vector );
}
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/201/

Comment: thanks works like a charm!! I was browsing the same issue and tried it like mr doob did in his last post but got some strange errors.